# How to copy a MS-Word "List Paragraph" Text String without it's Number in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an excel code which looks for a specific Heading and after It finds it I want to copy only **Text Strings** (Without their Numbers e.g. "1. ") of following List Paragraphs.

Here is my code so far (I omitted some parts of it for simplicity):

```
Private Sub CommandButton18_Click()

Dim Word As New Word.Application

Word.Selection.Find.Execute findtext:="Specific Heading"
Word.Selection.MoveDown wdLine, 1

    Do Until Word.Selection.Style <> "List Paragraph"
        Word.Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Copy

        '//At this part it copies both the list number and the text

        Word.Selection.MoveDown wdParagraph, 1
    Loop

end sub
```

Comment: This might work, insert within the `Do Until` loop - `Dim copyRng As Range: Set copyRng = Word.Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Duplicate: copyRng.SetRange copyRng.Start, copyRng.End - 1: copyRng.Copy`, basically you need to exclude copying the paragraph marker and you should get just the paragraph text. I won't recommend you selecting paragraphs here and there, you should work within `Paragraph` and `Range` object.

Comment: If you only need the content of the paragraph (i.e. formatting not needed) then you can also get it using `Word.Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text`

Comment: The fact you have 'copied' text implies you will subsequently 'paste' the text. In which case you turn off list numbering of the paragraph that has been pasted.

Comment: @RaymondWu It should work fine but since I running my macro in Excel VBA editor the ".end" method is considered as Excel's Range.end() method and it needs an argument. Any Suggestions?

Comment: Forgot you are working from non-Word, change the declaration to `Dim copyRng As Word.Range` @Milad

Comment: @RaymondWu I should be able to use ".copy" method to be able Paste it in an excel cell so "Word.Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text.copy" gives me an error.

Comment: @Milad `Word.Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text` Gives you a `String` value.. you store it in a string variable (like `strVariable = Word.Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text`) and if you want it to be inserted in an excel cell, something like `Range("A1").Value = strVariable`

Comment: @RaymondWu Thanks Raymond. Your last Comment did the job.

Comment: @freeflow Thanks. I used "Word.Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers" for each of my List Paragraphs before Copying them and it works too.